# How can I fix "unauthorized" error when accessing Report Portal API?

Tags: reportportal

How I can get access to API?

I'm getting

```
{
  "error": "unauthorized",
  "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

when trying to use `basic` authentication type.

Answer (score 5):

ReportPortal uses Oauth to authenticate clients. So, your header should look like:

`"Authorization" : "Bearer YOUR_TOKEN"`

ReportPortal provides two types of tokens: expiring and non-expiring. Expiring tokens are created for UI so that it can handle user sessions. Non-expiring tokens are introduced for API clients. Actually, non-expiring token can be found (and revoked) from user profile page:
[image: ReportPortal token]

Comment: Thanks! Works fine with a little adjustment. Please, correct Authentication -> Authorization.

Comment: @EugeneVictoroff could you please rename question. Change RP -> ReportPortal to help users with searching)