# REST API Documentation for reportportal

Tags: reportportal

We're using non-common proprietary java-based test tool/framework. And we've been looking for trying to couple it with reportportal. None of your existing agents fits to us, and that`s why we considered to try the pure REST-API integration. Could you please share API-documentation? 
P.S. I honestly tried to find it, but failed:)

Answer (score 9):

Agents documentation can be found on http://reportportal.io

There is also auth-generated Swagger API which is hosted on each ReportPortal instance:
http://your_host/ui/#api
Make sure you are logged in before opening swagger doc.

The best option for you is to take existing Java client for ReportPortal and use it to report data. You can find it here: 
https://github.com/reportportal/client-java
Pull requests and updates are highly welcomed!
Please, be noticed that right now we are working on new version of mentioned client which will be sending requests asynchronously. I would suggest contacting RP developers directly) to get more details on that.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same question, was looking for swagger doc in JSON format (since models are pretty complex and it's not really convenient to extract data from the UI).

Quite logical, found it at the same place, with slightly different url:

```
http://your_host:8080/api/v1/api-docs?access_token=your_access_token
```

Answer (score 0):

Base URL for making calls will be "http://your_host:8080/"
The calls are something like this: "http://host/api/v1/projectName/launch?filter.btw.startTime=0;120;+5"

For some calls you need full authorisation. In those, set header "Authorization" with bearer token found.
"Authorization" : "Bearer YOUR_TOKEN"

If you need to upload files to the "/log" endpoint, you need to give extra form parameters, "json_request_part=" and "file=@"

Some links to help in detail:
https://github.com/reportportal/reportportal/issues/704

[How can I fix "unauthorized" error when accessing Report Portal API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40759578/how-can-i-fix-unauthorized-error-when-accessing-report-portal-api)